# JQuery test for landscape or portrait image in Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify, flexslider

I'm developing a shopfront in Shopify and test whether a product image in a Flexslider is landscape or portrait:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function (){

      $('.flexslider .slides li img').each(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()) {
         $(this).addClass('slide-landscape');
         $('.flex-control-thumbs li img').addClass('thumb-landscape');

       } else if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
         $(this).addClass('slide-portrait');
         $('.flex-control-thumbs li img').addClass('thumb-portrait');
       }
     });
   });
 </script>
```

For some reason, the images all get the 'landscape' classes, and never the portrait. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be great.

Comment: It may be worth running your code under `$(window).on('load', fn)`, or under the load event of each individual image to ensure they have been received by the client and their height/width properties are accessible.

Comment: Thanks,  but still no luck. I'm using:

Comment: Thanks,  but still no luck. I'm using:

          <li data-thumb="{{ product | img_url: 'medium' }}" >
            <div class="prod-image-wrap">  
             <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
               <img src="{{ product | img_url: '420x420' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
            </a>
         </li>

for each image load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic if/else works for me to write classes to your main images. See fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/g28ugzdp](http://jsfiddle.net/g28ugzdp)

However the 2nd statement in each condition `$('.flex-control-thumbs li img').addClass(`...`);` actually adds the class to ALL images that are children of list items within the `flex-control-thumbs` class. See fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/g28ugzdp/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/g28ugzdp/1/)

You can solve for that in 1 of 2 ways.

1. If your thumbnail images are displayed at their correct aspect ratios, you can simply run the main loop over the `$('.flex-control-thumbs li img')` object in the same way that you do with `$('.flexslider .slides li img')`.
2. If your thumbnails need to have their classes match the main image, but don't render on the page in the correct aspect ratio, then I would use a `for` loop and the array properties of your javascript objects to select each image sequentially and modify the matching thumbnail with the same conditional logic. See code below: (also on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g28ugzdp/4/))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var images = $('.flexslider .slides li img'),
      thumbs = $('.flex-control-thumbs li img');
   
  for ( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
      if (images[i].width > images[i].height) {
        $(images[i]).addClass('slide-landscape');
        $(thumbs[i]).addClass('thumb-landscape');
      } else {
        $(images[i]).addClass('slide-portrait');
        $(thumbs[i]).addClass('thumb-portrait');
      }
  };
});
```

```css
.slide-landscape {border-top:8px solid orange;}
.slide-portrait {border-left:8px solid green;}

.thumb-landscape {border-top:4px solid red;}
.thumb-portrait {border-left:4px solid blue;}

li {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flexslider">
<article class="flex-control-thumbs">
<ul>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/40" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/40/20" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/40" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/40/20" /></li>
</ul>
</article>

<article class="slides">
<ul>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" /></li>
</ul>
</article>
</div>
```

Also you may want to set your `if` condition to be `>=` or change your `else if` to be just `else` so that you can catch any cases where the image is perfectly square.

Comment: Worth noting, I did run into a bug just now in my own code where all of the images were being assigned the 'portrait' class. I think that that bug came up because I didn't wait until the document was ready before I ran my code.

Comment: Excellent! That worked, and just what I was looking for. I'm sorry for myself that my js skills are not any better. Great to see from your profile that you volunteer as a barista. If you are ever in Dunedin, New Zealand, cafe Mazagran makes a great coffee – which I will buy!